# Unable to insert binary data from mssql into sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite, pyodbc

I am trying to query an Microsoft SQL 2005 database, process the data and write the keys to the data I updated to an sqllite3 database store locally on my machine.

The tools I'm using are python 2.7, pyodbc and sqllite3.  I am on windows 7 and the driver I've tried connecting to my mssql db using the sql server and sql native client driver with pyodbc and both yield the same results.

The field I am having issues with is a uuid field that is binary(16) in mssql.  When I query the data using pyodbc it is coming back to me in a bytearray().

This is the output I get when I run the following.

```
id = mycursor.fetchone()
print id
```

**àO÷�eÅO‹1ÝWt‘E**

```
repr(id)
```

**bytearray(b'\xe0O\xf7\x1d\x9de\xc5O\x8b1\x0e\xddWt\x91E')**

When I go to insert that Id into an sqllite3 database I get the following.

```
s = sqlite3.connect('tmp.db')
cursor = s.cursor()
s.execute("create table recs(uuid blob)")
s.commit()
s.execute("insert into recs (uuid) values(?)", id)
```

1 s.execute("insert into recs (uuid) values(?)", id)

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 16 supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python value needs to be a `buffer` object:

```
>>> s.execute("insert into recs (uuid) values(?)", (buffer(id), ))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x011CD2E0>
>>> r = s.execute("select * from recs").fetchone()
>>> r
(<read-write buffer ptr 0x011F9280, size 16 at 0x011F9260>,)
>>> r[0]
<read-write buffer ptr 0x011F9280, size 16 at 0x011F9260>
>>> str(r[0])
'\xe0O\xf7\x1d\x9de\xc5O\x8b1\x0e\xddWt\x91E'
>>> str(r[0]) == id
True
```

Comment: I take it back, that works!  I was missing the enclosing parenthesis.  Thank you so much !

Comment: MRAB I did some research and I get why the buffer is needed now but still unclear on why it needs to be in a tuple.

Comment: The `execute` method requires the values for the placeholders to be in a tuple. It just happens that in this case there's 1 placeholder, so it requires the value in a 1-tuple.